# A story where characters interact both in real life and in a collective dream, not "A Maze of Death"

Tags: story-identification

A few days ago I asked about a novel where characters interacted sometimes in real life and sometimes in a collective dream. In that case it was *A Maze of Death*, (or rather *Au bout du Labyrinthe*, since I read it in french translation) which was a duplicate.

That reminded me of another story with the same double type of interaction. But it is definitely not the same one. This one I read in English. I am positive of that because I had to look for the french translation of the verb "to shuffle".

From the context, it was obvious that this way of walking was a stereotype of African Americans, at least when the book was written, at least 40 years ago.

In fact this is almost the only thing I remember about this story. I don't remember whether it was a novel or short fiction, a whole book or in a collection, on Earth or in space....

But it was SF inasmuch as people could connect their minds to create a collective dream, just as in *A Maze of Death*. It might be by Philip K. Dick, but I am not at all sure it is the case.

It was probably also a murder mystery, because IRCC, one the characters who was African American (possibly the only one - and of course at that time this was not the phrase that was used) was a policeman or a detective. And he realised at some point that their collective dream had been taken over by a white supremacist, because he shuffled. And even in the dream he knew that he did **not** shuffle in real life. Or maybe it was when back in real life that he remembered that he had shuffled in the dream. Anyway, I think that the fact that someone had allowed his prejudices to enter the collective dream was very important in the plot.

Sorry I don't remember anything else.

Comment: collective dream + PKD = Ubik?

Comment: @user108131 I read a synopsis of Ubik on Wikipedia. It does not fit my memories at all. I don't remember such an intricate plot. Not to say mine was really simple, but definitely not the complexity of Ubik. And I did not see in Ubik any prominent African American, maybe not the *main* protagonist but among the half-dozen more important ones at most. Also I am not *sure* it is by PKD.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's PKD, then "[Eye in the Sky](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?9367)" fits all your points - a group of people share realities created by the imagination of the eight major characters after an incident with a particle accelerator. The book has an African American protagonist (Billy Law), and while I can't find my copy, one Goodreads review specifically mentions the word "shuffle" and its racist connotation:

> The story is about 8 people who are involved in an accident. While
> they're unconscious, they live through a series of worlds that trap
> them in the worldview of the mind of one after the other of the
> unconscious or semi-unconscious people. These are often hilarious and
> I laughed out loud several times. But they're also fascinating because
> it shows how our perceptions of the world are really quite different
> from one another. We see everything from a man who thinks that all
> black men "shuffle" and talk in dialect to what a paranoiac endures on
> a daily basis.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/165908.Eye_in_the_Sky

Comment: Page 75

The Negro’s face twitched in a spasm of acute, helpless misery. ‘‘In this world—’’ Sorrow blurred his eyes. ‘‘In this damn place, I’ve started to shuffle.”’

Comment: Page 101

“‘You’re what Silvester imagines a young radical college woman would look like. And he thinks all Negroes shuffle. This is going to be tough onallofus . . . unless we get out of Silvester’s world pretty damn soon, it’s going to be our finish.”’

Comment: https://archive.org/details/eyeinsky0000dick/mode/2up?q=shuffle

Comment: Definitely my story ! Thanks a lot ! The system says I have to wait before awarding you the bonus, but I'll do it as soon as  I can !